# Local variables in bash functions

Tags: bash, function

I am getting confused about setting local variables in bash functions.

It seems that using

```
  local dgt
  local ltr
  local braces
  local da
```

could be safer than using

```
  local dgt ltr braces da
```

I am worried about the possibility of a variable not getting defined as local, or not having the value set. Could that happen?

For instance, consider

```
local foo="$(mycmd)"
```

The exit status of the command is overridden by the exit status of the creation of the local variable.

Then the correct code would be

```
local foo
foo=$(mycmd)
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: then do it the way you want - both are valid - though, I struggle to understand what is *safe* about multiple lines vs one line

Comment: If I use things like `local dgt=3 ltr braces da ptr="cut"` I worry of instances where there could be problems with the variable definition as local.

Comment: what kind of problems are you thinking about? What do you mean "it _seems_ safer"?

Comment: Of not being defined as local, or not having the value set.  Could that happen?

Comment: Please be sure to add these details to the question, rather than collecting them in the comments. As you know, the comment section is rather cumbersome to read through, and comments may be removed without notice.

Comment: The Bash Reference description of the `local` built-in command is very specific. "For each argument, a local variable named *name* is created, and assigned *value*." The value is shown as optional in the syntax, and if omitted will be empty. Why are you suspicious about the behaviour of some unspecified instances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Of not being defined as local, or not having the value set. Could that
> happen?

It will also be defined as long as the local command itself is initially syntactically correct.  The local command doesn't care about the exit value of any command substitution (which executes in a subshell) that may happen before or after the local command's evaluation.

```
$ f() { local x=$(false); declare -p x; }; f; declare -p x
declare -- x=""
bash: declare: x: not found
```

This is true by intent at least.  Bugs however may not make it work the way you expect, particularly when [defining array values](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2014-12/msg00028.html) in earlier versions of Bash.  So indeed separating the definition from the declaration might be better, sometimes.

Comment: Right, it has been my experience of having strange unexpected values for arrays in early versions.  I thought the problems are still present in latest versions. but now people think that should be actually fine these days.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, some differences:

```
$ bash -c 'f() { local a="$(exit 3)" b="$?"; echo "$b"; }; f'
3
$ bash -c 'f() { local a="$(exit 3)"; local b="$?"; echo "$b"; }; f'
0
```

```
$ bash -c 'f() { local a="$(exit 3)" á=x b="$?"; echo "$? $b"; }; f'
environment: line 0: local: `á=x': not a valid identifier
1 3
```

```
$ mksh -c 'a=0; f(){ local á; local a; a=1; }; f; echo "$a"'
mksh: typeset: á: is not an identifier
0
$ mksh -c 'a=0; f(){ local á a; a=1; }; f; echo "$a"'
mksh: typeset: á: is not an identifier
1
```

Note that bash contrary to many other shells doesn't let you decalre a variable as `local` if it has been declared as `readonly` in a parent scope. Still, like for `local Ûnsupported¹ other_var`, in `local readonly_var other_var`, I find that in `bash`, `other_var` still ends up being declared as `local`.

---

<sup>¹ `local Ûnsupported` actually works in `bash`, but only in locales where that `Û` is encoded on a single byte (and is classified as `isalpha()`).</sup>